# Prove that if $f_n$ analitics converges uniformly to $f$ then $f_n^{'}$ converges uniformly to $f^{'}$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, uniform-convergence

$f_n:\Omega\ -> C$ analytics with $\Omega$ open subset of $C$, converges uniformly to $f$ on every K compact subset of $\Omega$

I tried working with the definition of uniform convergence but got nowhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Cauchy integral formula expresses $f'(a)$ in terms of an integral involving $f$ around a curve.

Comment: In addition, remember that uniform convergence allows you to interchange (contour) integration and taking a limit.

Comment: Is there any way to prove it without Cauchy's integral formula?

Comment: You could also do it using the Schwarz lemma.